# C++ copy/move and destructor invocations

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to understand why my destructor get invoked only twice in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class myclass{
public:
    int a, b, c;
    vector<int> mvec;
    ~myclass(){
        cout << "getting destroyed ...\n";
    }
};

myclass factory_method(){
    myclass a {9,99,999, {0,1,2,3}};
    //cout << a;
    return a;
}

void test_func(){
    cout << "====\n";
    myclass b = factory_method();
    myclass c {b};
}

int main (){
    test_func();
    return 0;
}

// prints the following
//====
//getting destroyed ...
//getting destroyed ...
```

As I understand, the compiler generates copy/move constructors and assignment functions, which I can see working.

But in this piece of code I'm creating 3 objects, 1 in `factory_method` on stack (which is moved and I understand that). This object `a` will be destroyed when its stack frame is destroyed, then in `test_func`, object `b` is moved to, from `factory_method` and object `c` is created by compiler generated copy constructor on object `b`. Both object `b` and `c` should get destroyed when `test_func` stack frame gets destroyed and I should see 3 'getting destroyed' messages.

I get only two, am I missing something? Can someone please explain?

Thank you!

Comment: The compiler is doing optional copy-elision here. If you turn that off you get 3 destructor [calls](https://godbolt.org/z/Eo9nqW).

Comment: See return value optimization

Comment: @cigien : thank you! and special thanks for the link to godbolt.org, a new tool for me to explore! :)

Comment: You're welcome :) It's a lot of fun, and you can play with lots of settings, like different compilers/ versions/ etc... :)